# Angular 7 mat-select problem with 3 dots of css "ellipsis"

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I have a problem with a mat-select propriety "**ellipsis**".
the 3 points are of a different color than the text color. I tried to do but they continue to be 3 black dots instead to be white

```
   ::ngdeep .example{
        color: white
    }
```

[image]

Comment: `class` is a keyword try to use different name as `selector` and coming to the color `color:white;` should work in this case mean wherever you're using `ellipsis` code you just have to use `color`.

Comment: "class" is an example. Now I edited it in "example", maybe it's clearer now

Comment: @Manjuboyz I know i use color:white; but it doesn't work only in "mat-Select" ,

Comment: @RiccardoF. Can you please create a StackBlitz with your setup and problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems like the it seems that the values ​​of the various css overlap, you can add "***::ng-deep***" and "***!important***" , it worked for me . Try to use a snippet like this in your CSS:

```
 ::ng-deep .mat-select .mat-select-value-text {
     color: white !important;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Elipssis works with width and overflow hidden, here is a code you can try

```
.example{
  white-space: nowrap; 
  width: 50px; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis; }
```

Thanks